# redis keys command does not work with certain characters

Tags: regex, redis, key

I can't figure out why certain `redis KEYS` commands are behaving like this.

This returns all keys starting with "string:term":

```
keys "tag:[term]*"
```

When I put a `.js` in (even escaping it), it returns **all** keys that contain `.js` - the second part of the "regex" I'm trying to include:

```
keys "tag:[term\.com]*"; 
keys "tag:[term.com]*";
```

For some background, the [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/keys) implies regular expressions within square brackets:

> h[ae]llo matches hello and hallo, but not hillo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KEYS command does not use regular expressions but [glob-style pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) (compatible with the basic Unix shells).

```
keys "tag:[term]*"
```

does return many more keys than "all keys starting with tag:term". It returns all keys starting with tag: plus a single character among [ 't', 'e', 'r', 'm' ].

To return all keys starting with tag:term, you need to use "tag:term*"

The documentation does not implies regular expressions, just glob-style patterns.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. Any idea why the period would throw things off?

Comment: The . character has no special meaning with glob.